# Record separators in text files written by a Fortran program

Tags: windows, macos, fortran, text-files, gfortran

As a part of a larger program, written in the new Fortran standard, I am interested to write some text on a file that will be read by another program over which I have no control.
Long ago when I learned Fortran an output record generated by a format statement should begin with an LF (linefeed) and end with a CR (carriage return).  This means that each output record should be separated by a sequence CRLF.

To my surprise I find that this seems no longer to be true except when I compile and run my program on a Windows computer.  When I compile and run my program on a Mac the output records are separated by a single LF.  I know this is a Linux standard but I guess I assumed the output from a Fortran program should not depend on the operating system.

The consequence of this is that when I generate the output on Windows my output file can be read by the other program (which only exists on Windows) whereas when I generate the same output on my Mac it fails.
I have no idea how the other program reads the file but I assume it is a standard Fortran read.

I have also compared my output file from Windows and Mac using "diff" and that indicates all lines are different.  However "diff -w" indicates the files are identical.

I would like to be able to generate output that can be read by the other program independently if I generate the file on a Mac or Windows.  I know I can use things like #ifdef to check the OS when I compile but I wonder if there is any other way, are there some option in the Fortran write?  I know there are a lot of new things line "noadvance" etc.  Any option to force a "CRLF" record separator?

I use GNU Fortran version 5.2 on Windows and what seems to be called version 7.2 on the Mac

Comment: That has never been true. That must have been a feature of a particular compiler on some particular platform.

Comment: You can always convert the files by `unix2dos`. But the thing to really blame is the external program. It is at fault that it does not understand normal unix text files. But I understand you have to work with what you have.

Comment: Program to the lowest common denominator - Windows. Then, if you are subsequently lucky enough to have a superior OS like macOS or Linux, you will have the tools (such as `dos2unix`) at your disposal to carry on working.

Comment: With Intel Fortran you can set the `RECORDTYPE` environment variable. But I don't know of anything like that for gfortran.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The point is Fortran puts the record markers automatically. In different ways in Windows and in Linux. And even more  differently on record-oriented platforms.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gfortran/Extended-I_002fO-specifiers.html#Extended-I_002fO-specifiers), gfortran allows a peculiar flag for the `OPEN` statement, called `CARRIAGECONTROL`, as in:

```
program prg

    integer :: u

    open (newunit = u, file = 'test.txt', carriagecontrol = 'fortran')

    write (u, '(A,I2)') '-', 12
    write (u, '(A,I2)') '-', 34

    close (u)

end program prg
```

This option is only supported when the code is compiled with the **-fdec** switch. The content of the output file is then:

```
> hexdump -C test.txt
00000000  0a 31 32 0d 0a 33 34 0d                           |.12..34.|
00000008
```

which is exactly the format that you described. The minus signs in the I/O lists in the above code are consumed by the compiler runtime library and used to redefine the output format. (Tested with gfortran 9.2.)